# SSL local/remote Cert for DotNetCore API

Tags: docker, certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a newbie when it comes to certificates.

I'm building a Linux docker image with a Dot Net Core REST WebAPI app that will host the backend for a game.  I plan to host this backend on Azure using a Container Instance.

I'd like all communication to be via SSL.  I've created a self-signed cert for local communication from my Windows machine to the container.  Once I registered it in my hosts file, the self-signed cert is working fine locally.

Now I'm ready to host on Azure.  I'm prepared to obtain a CA cert, but am trying to work out how to maintain local access w/o cert errors as well as public access w/o cert errors without modifying the container between my local/debug sessions and the production/remote sessions.  I'd prefer to have a single certificate, if possible.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to setup a cert for this situation?  Seems like a common need, but I'm not finding resources to walk me through it.  Thanks!

Comment: And just saw some guidance that perhaps setting up an API Gateway w/SSL termination may be the way to go, but it still didn't discuss how to have the cert be valid for local development.  If API GW is a good idea, can you comment on how to set up the local dev as well?

Comment: If you use the URL of Azure WebApp like mysite.azurewebsites.net is already served via SSL you don't need a certificate, otherwise, if you use a custom domain, you must buy a new Certificate then copy it to the Linux container and configure the API. If you use a SelfSigned Certificate the WebApp work only on your machine, other machines receive the Warning about the certificate is not being trusted.